# C: pointer to struct in the struct definition

Tags: c, struct, pointers

How can I have a pointer to the next struct in the definition of this struct:

```
typedef struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
  A*  next;
} A;
```

this is how I first wrote it but it does not work.

Comment: Note C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3): _A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), …_

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can define the typedef and forward declare the struct first in one statement, and then define the struct in a subsequent definition.

```
typedef struct A A;

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    A* next;
};
```

Edit: As others have mentioned, without the forward declaration the struct name is still valid inside the struct definition (i.e. you can used `struct A`), but the typedef is not available until after the typedef definition is complete (so using just `A` wouldn't be valid). This may not matter too much with just one pointer member, but if you have a complex data structure with lots of self-type pointers, may be less wieldy.

Comment: This is the "canonical" way of doing this.

Comment: unwind: many coding style conventions for C vehemently oppose typedefing structs. I wouldn't say it's canonical at all.

Comment: If I could vote up comments, Chris Young would get a +1.  There is a huge difference between native types and aggregate structures.  **Don't** hide it behind a typedef.

Comment: @ephemient: You can now.

Comment: @ephemient Why should I not hide it? They're just implementation details.

Comment: Why are there two 'A's in typedef struct A A; ?

Comment: @turner: because one `A` identifies the structure type in `struct A`, and the second gives the type a name (alias) of `A`.  If you had `typedef int B;`, then `int` is the type and `B` is the new name for the type.  In the same way, with `typedef struct A A;`, then `struct A` is the type and `A` is the new name for the type.

Answer (score 68):

In addition to the first answer, without a typedef and forward declaration, this should be fine too.

```
struct A 
{ 
    int a; 
    int b; 
    struct A *next; 
};
```

Comment: Plus without typedefs you actually know if you're dealing with a struct in the code

Answer (score 21):

You are missing the `struct` before the `A*`

```
  typedef struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    struct A* next;
  } A;
```

Answer (score 14):

You can go without forward declaration:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
    struct A *next;
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Please, you're in C, not C++.

If you really must typedef a struct (and most programmers that I work with would not¹), do this:

```
typedef struct _A {
    int a;
    int b;
    struct _A *next;
} A;
```

to clearly differentiate between `_A` (in the `struct` namespace) and `A` (in the type namespace).

¹`typedef` hides the size and storage of the type it points to ― the argument (and I agree) is that in a low-level language like C, trying to hide anything is harmful and counterproductive.  Get used to typing `struct A` whenever you mean `struct A`.

Comment: How does "struct A" tell me anything about its size?

Comment: It tells you that it's an aggregate structure, and thus many things like passing it as arguments, returning it, comparisons, and `a = b` are inefficient or will not work.

Comment: _A is a reserved name. A_ would be fine.

Comment: Nitpick: _A is a bad name: leading underscores belong to the compiler.  [edit] Damn, I think I just echoed MSalters.

Comment: I have never, in all my time programming, encountered a problem from giving the struct and the typedef the same name, and then I only bother giving the struct a name in this exact case (linked lists etc). I think you are just promoting FUD. Can you give an example where it causes problems to give the same name for both? Also I have never encountered any issue by using typedef on all my structs whatsoever, so I find your argument that it is 'harmful and counterproductive' to be a bit over the top.

Comment: Note that the `_A` in `struct _A` is in the 'tag' name space; the `A` at the end of the `typedef` is in the 'ordinary identifiers' name space (shared with variable names, function names, type names, etc).  To the extent there is a structure name space, it means the set of structure member names (and each structure or union type has its own name space).  See C11 [§6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3).

Comment: Note that you should not, in general, create function, variable, tag or macro names that start with an underscore. Part of [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says: — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ — _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ See also [What does double underscore (`__const`) mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449301)

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
 values
} NAME;
```

This is shorter way to typedef a struct i think its the easiest notation, just don't put the name infront but behind.

you can then call it like

```
NAME n;  

NAME *n; // if you'd like a ptr to it.
```

Anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: well as stated in the question, the need is to have a pointer INSIDE the struct (chained list) so I don't see what your answer add here.