# Why structure can not contain Instance of itself?

Tags: c++, structure

I read about structure in c++ that it can not contain instance of itself.
Can anybody help me to understand why it can not contain instance of itself?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition

Comment: How big would the structure be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because to create the instance of it, you will need to create the variable, which is itself an instance of it - which will invoke the constructor.

This will result in infinite recursive call to the constructor.

Assume `class A` has an instance variable named `a`:

Invoking the constructor of `A` will cause the initialization of `a`, which is itself an `A`. To do it - the constructor of `A` will be invoked again.

Note that it will not even compile because the compiler cannot allocate the memory for it, it doesn't know how much space to allocate for each object. How much space does it take to store the instance variable `a`? [Any finite space will not be enough because there will always be an extra variable which also needs to be allocated]

Comment: "How much space does it take to store the instance variable a" - as a special case, any size would work provided that `A` has no other data members or base classes that occupy space. But it's hardly worth allowing it only in a case where it would be useless.

Comment: It should be pointed out that you can create an instance dynamically and store a pointer to it in the same struct, basically creating a forward list. `struct S{ int data; S* next; }`

Comment: how does java works then ?

Comment: @Learner Java objects allocation are references. `class A { A a; }` means there is reference to `A`, not the object itself. This means you don't need to allocate an `A` inside it, and your constructor doesn't have to allocate (and call its constructor recursively).

Answer (score 9):

Because then it would take up "infinite" storage since when it is initialised it recursively initialises itself. You can store pointers to the same structure, however.

e.g. This is invalid:

```
struct a
{
    int someVar;
    a bad;
};
```

This is valid (say if you want a linked list of this structure):

```
struct a
{
    int someVar;
    a* good;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

```
struct bedroom
{
    bed b;
    table t;
    bedroom r;
};
```

Do you see the problem now? A bedroom would need storage for an infinite amount of beds and tables.

Comment: But it's turtles all the way down!

Comment: What are you doing with a table in your bedroom?

Comment: @sbi: Putting my C++ books on it?

Comment: @Fred: Don't you keep them under your pillow?

Comment: @sbi: I have far too many C++ books to keep them all under my pillow.

Comment: @FredOverflow: You don't need to have _all of them_ in your bedroom _all the time_. Besides, sleeping in a half-sitting position is better for your headdress anyway.

Comment: @sbi: Where else would I keep them, in the kitchen? I don't have a separate living room.

Comment: @FredOverflow: "I don't have a separate living room." _So it's your combined bed and living room we're talking about?_ Well, then it's of course not surprising you have a table there! See, I _knew_ something was fishy with this. No sane person has a table in their bed room. Case closed now. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Don't you even have a nightstand in your bedroom?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Of course I have one, and it's full of books! But no table.

Comment: @sbi: I thought a nightstand was a kind of table, sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

Because then it would lead to inifite recursion. e.g.

```
struct foo
{
    int boo;
    foo f;
};

foo f;
```

`foo` would contain a `foo` which contains a `foo` etc...

To get around it you should use a pointer:

```
struct foo
{
    int boo;
    foo* f;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

not just structure any incomplete data type cannot be used with in it.
lets say u have a structure A and u have included the same structure as a member,now when compiler tries to allocate memory to it how does it know how much to allocate because u have declared structure A inside it which is not yet completely defined and it will throw an error incomplete data type not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers point out, the structure cannot contain an instance of itself, because that would result in an infinite recursion when creating the structure.  However a structure *can* contain a pointer to itself:

```
struct foo
{
    int boo;
    foo *f;
};

foo f;
f.f = &f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is impossible to create memory layout for such structure. If a `struct foo` contains an `int` and a `foo`, how would you fit `sizeof(int)+sizeof(foo)` bytes into `sizeof(foo)` bytes? The equation `A+B=A` does not have any solutions for `A,B > 0`.