# Self Referenced Class in Java

Tags: java, c, self-reference

I understand that in c self-referential structures are allowed but the self-included ones are not. Borrowing the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360509/why-structure-can-not-contain-instance-of-itself):

Invalid:

```c
struct a
{
    int someVar;
    a bad;
};
```

Valid:

```c
struct a
{
    int someVar;
    a* good;
};
```

But in Java the following class is valid:

```java
class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;
}
```

This looks more like the invalid example in c. My question is: why is this legal in Java?

I have a feeling that this is related to the fact that in Java you only have access to references (like pointers), not the actual objects, but I still don't fully understand this. And searching for "self-referential in Java" does not give a lot of related information. Can anyone give some hints? Thanks!

Comment: In Java, _all_ object variables are references. There's no "inclusion" to be possible.

Comment: We say “reference”, but Node is a pointer, the same way a* is. So there is no difference between Java and c here.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- right this is very spot on thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java hides some implementation details from you that C does not.

In Java, any instance of a class is a reference i.e. a pointer to an object without explicitly using a pointer.

In C there are no references, only values.  So you need to explicitly use a pointer value to hold the address of an object to essentially have a reference to it.

Comment: Oh right! Just to make sure, then is it correct to say that `Node` in `Node next` is different from that in `class Node`? The former means a reference to `Node`, the latter is the actual object?

Comment: @Patrick The point where `class Node` appears is the start of the definition of the class.  `Node next` is defining a variable of that type, and in Java all object variables are references.