# Making a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, visual-studio-2012

```
typedef struct{
    char name[25];
    int yearOfBirth;
    int district;
    char gender;
    int age;

    CitizenType *next;

}CitizenType;
```

When I try to make a Linked List in this format in Visual Studio, I get all sorts of errors relating to syntax. (102 in total) but when I comment out the CitizenType *next; I get no errors. I realize it has something to do with referencing the structure before it has been completely declared, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
typedef struct node{
    char name[25];
    int yearOfBirth;
    int district;
    char gender;
    int age;

    struct node *next;

}CitizenType;
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition) stack overflow answer for more information about self referenced structs in C. From the answer:

> A CitizenType cannot contain another CitizenType as it becomes
>   a never-ending recursion.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It compiles! Thank you! I'll have to do some reading. Much appreciated.

Comment: great @DaveMcGregor, mark this answer or the one that you like the most as 'the answer' of your question. For more info about the site I recommend you to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Welcome to SO!

Comment: @cacho umm.. He is pointing to another CitizenType and not creating a never-ending recursion.. I think the reason his original code did not work is that typedef should appear before it is actually used. By replacing it with struct node *next, you are just not using the typedef before it is defined. I think your answer is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Neo, I understood that the recursion(from the answer linked) it refers that you are trying to define a datatype, but inside the datatype is the datatype itself. Sorry if I am not very clear with this, do we agree now?

Answer (score 4):

Declare the typedef before (and separately from) the structure.

```
typedef struct citizen_type CitizenType;

struct citizen_type {
    ...
    CitizenType *next;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
CitizenType
```

enters into the namespace of types only after the structure ends.

So you can use the new type only after its declaration.

You can use instead of it a `struct name` (giving a name to the struct), or declaring the type before to declare the structure with a name, as in previous post.