# Error occurred when using structure in C language programing

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

At the beginning, my code looked like this，and I compiled the code using gcc

```
struct pcb{
    int pid;            /* process id */
    int ppid;           /* parent process id */
    int prio;           /* priority */
};
/* process node */
struct pnode{
    pcb *node;
    pnode   *sub;
    pnode   *brother;
    pnode   *next;
};
```

And it sends the message that unknown type name '`pcb`'.  Then I modify the code according to what I found in the Internet, and my revised code is as follows.

```
typedef struct pcb{
    int pid;            /* process id */
    int ppid;           /* parent process id */
    int prio;           /* priority */
    int state;          /* state */
    int lasttime;       /* last execute time */
    int tottime;        /* totle execute time */
} pcb;
/* process node */
typedef struct pnode{
    pcb *node;
    pnode   *sub;
    pnode   *brother;
    pnode   *next;
} pnode;
```

But new errors occurred; the compiler sent the message about unknown type name '`pnode`' to me. I don't know how to using my structure variable when I define a structure. Please give me some tips.

Comment: Related to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/588623/694576 if not a duplicate to it.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword `struct` is required in C to declare variable having structure type.

```
struct pcb{
    int pid;            /* process id */
    int ppid;           /* parent process id */
    int prio;           /* priority */
};
/* process node */
struct pnode{
    struct pcb *node;
    struct pnode   *sub;
    struct pnode   *brother;
    struct pnode   *next;
};
```

You can use forward declaration to avoid writing many `struct`.

```
typedef struct pcb{
    int pid;            /* process id */
    int ppid;           /* parent process id */
    int prio;           /* priority */
    int state;          /* state */
    int lasttime;       /* last execute time */
    int tottime;        /* totle execute time */
} pcb;
/* process node */
typedef struct pnode pnode;
struct pnode{
    pcb *node;
    pnode   *sub;
    pnode   *brother;
    pnode   *next;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
struct pcb{
    int pid;            /* process id */
    int ppid;           /* parent process id */
    int prio;           /* priority */
};
/* process node */
struct pnode{
    struct pcb *node;
    struct pnode   *sub;
    struct pnode   *brother;
    struct pnode   *next;
};
```

Or

```
struct pcb;
typedef struct pcb pcb_t;
struct pnode;
typedef struct pnode pnode_t;

struct pcb{
    int pid;            /* process id */
    int ppid;           /* parent process id */
    int prio;           /* priority */
};
/* process node */
struct pnode{
    pcb_t *node;
    pnode_t *sub;
    pnode_t *brother;
    pnode_t *next;
};
```

Comment: In the second example, it would be sufficient to use the two `typedef` lines; the `struct xyz;` lines aren't needed (though they do no harm other than add to the number of lines to be processed).

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the [uasge of the keyword 'typedef'](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_typedef.htm), the type definition is only allowed to be used after `typedef struct pnode pnode;` has been defined.

So you have two choices to fix the error.

1. Define `typedef struct pnode pnode;` before you use the type `pnode *sub;`.
2. Modify your `typedef struct pnode` to:

   `typedef struct pnode{
   pcb *node;
   struct pnode *sub;

   struct pnode *brother;
   struct pnode *next;
   } pnode;`