# How to insert element into this struct

Tags: c

I am newer to C and do some practice,in this example,i want construct a table which can contains alot of element which is Symbol type,but i don't konw how to write that part.I want to use malloc to allocate heap memory to Symbol and insert into the table(SymbolTable).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {

    char *name;
    uint32_t addr;
}Symbol;

typedef struct {
    Symbol* tbl;
    uint32_t len;
    uint32_t cap;
    int mode;
} SymbolTable; /*this is the table i want to mantiply*/

SymbolTable* create_table(int mode) {
    SymbolTable* st = (SymbolTable*)malloc(sizeof(SymbolTable));
    if (st != NULL)
    {
        st->mode = mode;
        st->len = 0;
        return st;
    }
    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    return NULL;
}

void free_table(SymbolTable* table) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < table->len; ++i)
    {
        free(table->tbl[i].name);
        free(&(table->tbl[i]));
    }
    free(table);
}

int add_to_table(SymbolTable* table, const char* name, uint32_t addr) {
    if (addr % 4 != 0)
    {
        printf("Address alignment erron!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int table_len = table->len;
    if (table->mode == 1)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < table_len; ++i)
        {
            if (*((table->tbl[i]).name) == *name)
            {
                printf("Name existed!\n");
                return -1;
            }
            `I don't know how to inset element here`
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    SymbolTable * st = create_table(0);
    add_to_table(st, "aaa", 4);
    add_to_table(st, "bb", 8);
    write_table(st, stdout);
    free_table(st);
}
```

Comment: "I don't know how to write that part" is not a specific question. We won't just write the whole thing for you. Please explain more specifically what is preventing you from writing the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
You might also want to read up on the concept of [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Or were you aware of that concept and only asking for the code? In that case see the comment by @kaylum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with your code as it is; also, I had to make a few assumptions since you didn't specify those details in your question:

1. `cap` is the capacity of `table->tbl`, i.e. how much memory we have allocated
2. When adding a new symbol, we should copy the string containing its name, rather than just assigning that pointer to our new `Symbol` entry.

You should also pick one coding style and stick to it (braces on same vs new line,  `T* ptr` vs `T *ptr` etc). Finally, I've removed the cast in `create_table`; see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Here is a fixed version of your code; in `add_to_table`, if we don't have enough memory to add a new one, we double the capacity of our `Symbol` array (calling `realloc` every single time to add space for one more element would be wasteful). When we extend the capacity of our array, we must take care to set each `name` pointer to `NULL`, because if we don't and `free_table` is called when `cap` > `len`, we'd be trying to `free` an uninitialized pointer (whereas calling `free` on `NULL` is perfectly fine and does nothing).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    uint32_t addr;
} Symbol;

typedef struct
{
    Symbol* tbl;
    uint32_t len;
    uint32_t cap;
    int mode;
} SymbolTable; /*this is the table i want to mantiply*/

SymbolTable* create_table(int mode)
{
    SymbolTable* st = malloc(sizeof(SymbolTable));
    if (st != NULL)
    {
        st->tbl = NULL;
        st->mode = mode;
        st->len = 0;
        st->cap = 0;
        return st;
    }
    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    return NULL;
}

void free_table(SymbolTable* table)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < table->cap; ++i)
    {
        free(table->tbl[i].name);
    }
    free(table->tbl);
    free(table);
}

int add_to_table(SymbolTable* table, const char* name, uint32_t addr)
{
    if (addr % 4 != 0)
    {
        printf("Address alignment erron!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int table_len = table->len;
    if (table->mode == 1)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < table_len; ++i)
        {
            if (!strcmp(table->tbl[i].name, name))
            {
                printf("Name existed!\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }

        if (table_len + 1 > table->cap)
        {
            // allocate more memory
            uint32_t new_cap = table->cap ? table->cap * 2 : 2;
            table->tbl = realloc(table->tbl, new_cap * sizeof(*table->tbl));
            if (table->tbl == NULL)
            {
                // handle the error
            }

            table->cap = new_cap;
            int i;
            for (i = table_len; i < new_cap; ++i)
            {
                table->tbl[i].name = NULL;
            }
        }

        uint32_t name_len = strlen(name);
        table->tbl[table_len].name = malloc(name_len + 1);
        strncpy(table->tbl[table_len].name, name, name_len);
        table->tbl[table_len].name[name_len] = '\0';

        table->tbl[table_len].addr = addr;
        table->len++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    SymbolTable*  st = create_table(1);
    add_to_table(st, "aaa", 4);
    add_to_table(st, "bb", 8);
    write_table(st, stdout);
    free_table(st);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you need to allocate `*tbl` and set `cap` (if he contain the max nb of cell in your table) in `create_table()`.

Next, in `add_to_table()`, try to `malloc(sizeof(struct symbol))` if `(len < cap)` and allocate memory for `*name`, and set up to your value (don't forget the `\0` at the end of `*name`). Assign this to `tbl[len]` and do not forget to increment `len`.

Try to separate in little function, like `int is_in_table(const char *name)` who return the index or -1, or `symbol new_symbol(const char *name, Uint32 addr)` who create and set new symbol.

I hope that I have been useful for you :).

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of implementing Self-Referential structure.
Giving hints:

```
typedef struct S{
    char *name;
    uint32_t addr;
    S* next;
}Symbol;

typedef struct {
    Symbol* tbl;
    uint32_t len;
    int mode;
} SymbolTable;
```

http://www.how2lab.com/programming/c/link-list1.php

[self referential struct definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition)

Possible Implementation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
typedef struct S{
    char *name;
    uint32_t addr;
    S* next;
}Symbol;

typedef struct {
    Symbol* tbl;
    uint32_t len;
    int mode;
} SymbolTable; /*this is the table I want to maltiply*/

SymbolTable* create_table(int mode) {
    SymbolTable* st = (SymbolTable*)malloc(sizeof(SymbolTable));
    if (st != NULL)
    {
        st->tbl = NULL;
        st->mode = mode;
        st->len = 0;
        return st;
    }
    printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
    return NULL;
}

void free_table(SymbolTable* table) {
    free(table);
}

int add_to_table(SymbolTable* table,  char* name, uint32_t addr) {
    if (addr % 4 != 0)
    {
        printf("Address alignment erron!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int table_len = table->len;
    if (table->mode == 1)
    {
        if (table_len == 0)
        {
            Symbol *t = (Symbol*)malloc(sizeof(Symbol));
            t->name = name;
            t->next = NULL;
            table->len++;
            table->tbl = t;
        }
        else
        {
            Symbol *t = table->tbl;
            while (t->next != NULL)
            {
                if (t->name == name)
                {
                    printf("Name existed!\n");
                    return -1;
                }
                t = t->next;
            }   
            if (t->name == name)
            {
                printf("Name existed!\n");
                return -1;
            }
            t->next = (Symbol*)malloc(sizeof(Symbol));
            table->len++;
            t->next->name = name;
            t->next->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void write_table(SymbolTable *st)
{
    Symbol *t = st->tbl;
    while (t != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",t->name);
        t = t->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    SymbolTable *st = create_table(0);
    st->mode = 1;// Table mode setting to 1 for importing next value to table.
    // You may implement it in your own way.
    add_to_table(st, "cc", 8);
    st->mode = 1;
    add_to_table(st, "bb", 8);
    st->mode = 1;
    write_table(st);
    free_table(st);
}
```