# declare element in array that is the struct type

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, undeclared-identifier

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    node_t * otherNodes;
} node_t;
```

where I need an array of nodes in my node....

but in the header file is not recognized: it tell me `unknown type name 'node_t'

how can I solve this?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [self referential struct definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition)

Comment: I'll try.. but I need an array of other nodes

Comment: The solution is to name the structure itself. Then you can *forward declare* the type-alias if you want. Or use the structure name when declaring the member.

Comment: You might want to read [comp.lang.c FAQ list - Question 1.14](http://c-faq.com/decl/selfrefstruct.html)

Comment: Have you learned how to use a `struct` *without* using `typedef`? Because that would have probably prevented this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    node_t * otherNodes;
} node_t;
```

the name `node_t` within the structure definition is an undeclared name. So the compiler will issue an error.

You need to write for example

```
typedef struct node_t {
    int id;
    struct node_t * otherNodes;
} node_t;
```

Or you could write

```
typedef struct node_t node_t;

struct node_t {
    int id;
    node_t * otherNodes;
};
```

Or even like

```
struct node_t typedef node_t;

struct node_t {
    int id;
    node_t * otherNodes;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I referenced defenition of `struct list_head` from kernel codes:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/types.h?h=v5.10.84#n178

So I would write like this:

```
struct node {
    int id;
    struct node * otherNodes;
};

typedef struct node node_t;
```