# Why can you use a typedef'd struct before the typedef?

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef

Here's a MWE:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_type {
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
} node;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    node* n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
}
```

Not having `struct` before `node*` in the struct definition will error; `node` has not yet been defined. However, `struct node*` works fine, even though only `struct node_type` has been defined at this point. Why does this work?

Intuitively, it compiles if the struct is defined with `struct node_type*` for its fields, or if there is an explicit typedef before and the fields are of type `node*`. However, I don't understand why an in-line typedef allows the fields to be of type `struct node*` but not of type `node*`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition

Comment: Instead of `struct node* next;` etc you can use `struct node_type* next;` etc, which is the point of having that tag: so you can self-reference.

Comment: Aside: instead of `node* n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` I suggest `node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);` which is cleaner and less error-prone.

Comment: Note that even after the typedef definition is complete, `struct node` is a different type than `node` (or `struct node_type`).  More likely than not, that constitutes a serious flaw in your type's definition, which I anticipate would cause a watchful compiler to complain about some of the uses of that type.

Comment: `typedef` is *never* required in C code, and as a matter of style, I dislike most uses of it. I especially dislike it being introduced to C students early in a course, because it is very frequently misunderstood, and those misunderstandings interfere with learning the language.  Such as seems to be the case here.

Comment: Re "*`struct node*`*", Don't you want `struct node_type*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Not having struct before node* in the struct definition will error;
> node has not yet been defined. However, struct node* works fine, even
> though only struct node_type has been defined at this point.

In this typedef declaration

```
typedef struct node_type {
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
} node;
```

there are declared two structure types. The first one, `struct node_type`, is a complete type, and the second one, `struct node`, is an incomplete type.

Apart from these declarations, the code introduces an alias `node` for the type specifier `struct node_type`.

You may write

```
node* n = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

but you may not write for example

```
n->next = ( node * )malloc( sizeof( node ) );
```

or

```
n->next = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

because the type `struct node` is an incomplete type. Its size is unknown. And `struct node *` and `node *` are incompatible pointer types.

As for your question then if you will write for example

```
typedef struct node_type {
    node* next;
    node* prev;
} node;
```

then in these member declarations

```
node* next;
node* prev;
```

the name `node` is not defined yet. So, the compiler issues an error message.

Answer (score 2):

> However, `struct node*` works fine, even though only `struct node_type` has been defined at this point. Why does this work?

C has separate name spaces for ordinary identifiers and for structure tags (and union tags and enumeration tags).

`typedef type name` defines `name` to be an ordinary identifier for `type`. You can use `name` for `type` after this declaration but not before it. (Specifically, the point at which  `name` can be used is the end of its *declarator*, a part fo the C grammar including the name and any parentheses for function parameters or brackets for array sizes that are with it.)

`struct tag` declares `tag` to be a tag for the structure as soon as it appears.

In this code:

```
typedef struct node_type {
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
} node;
```

As soon as `struct node` appears, `node` is known as a tag, so it can be used as a name for a structure, even if the full definition of the structure is not known. However, here you have `struct node_type` and `struct node` referring to different things. You probably meant to use the same tag:

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
} node;
```

Now, where `struct node` appears in the second line (and the third), `node` is already known as a tag for a structure from the first line. So `struct node` in the second line and the third line refer to the same type as `struct node` in the first line.

In contrast, the `node` as an ordinary identifier in the `typedef` does not appear until the last line, so it is not known until later. So the second and third lines cannot use `node` as a type name.

Although `struct node` may be known as a type, its full definition is not initially known. Because of this, you cannot declare a member of that type, such as `struct node x;`. However, you can declare a pointer to the structure, `struct node *next;`, because the pointer type is already known. All pointers to structures have the same size and representation. So a compiler does not need to know what is in a structure to know how to make a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `node` without `struct` if you declare it before use in `struct` declaration using the ***forward declaration*** which will declare an *incomplete* type:

```
typedef struct node_type node;

struct node_type{
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    node* n =malloc(sizeof(*n));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KoWdfG8dn

> Why can you use a typedef'd struct before the typedef?

Because at this point this new type is not known to the compiler.

> Not having struct before node* in the struct definition will error;
> node has not yet been defined. However, struct node* works fine, even
> though only struct node_type has been defined at this point. Why does
> this work?

because you forward declare the new `struct` with the tag `node`.  It does nothing in common with your structs here.
Example:

```
typedef struct node_type {
    struct something* next;
    struct something_else* prev;
} node;
```

In the example above you declare two incomplete types `struct something` and `struct something_else`

From GNU C manual:

*A type that has not been fully defined is called an incomplete type. Structure and union types are incomplete when the code makes a forward reference, such as struct foo, before defining the type. An array type is incomplete when its length is unspecified.
You can’t use an incomplete type to declare a variable or field, or use it for a function parameter or return type. The operators sizeof and _Alignof give errors when used on an incomplete type.
However, you can define a pointer to an incomplete type, and declare a variable or field with such a pointer type. In general, you can do everything with such pointers except dereference them.*

https://godbolt.org/z/vbxMG5zK6

Comment: The "yes you can" part of this answer responds to a different question than was posed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger changed wording. It was to show how to forward declare something and I think it is exactly what he wants here

Comment: A forward declaration is an acceptable way to go, albeit not what the OP appears to have been *trying* to do.  In any case the response to "Why can you use a typedef'd struct before the typedef?", which I was including in "the 'yes you can' part", still does not make sense.  This answer would be improved by answering the actual question posed first.  If you want to talk about forward declarations too then fine, but going there first confuses the issue.

Comment: I have answered all questions

Comment: There seems to be an editing error here, or something -- currently it replies to "Why can you use a typedef'd struct before the typedef?" with "Because at this point this new type is not known to the compiler."

Comment: @ruakh I have no clue, what you mean