# C structure with pointer to self

Tags: c, struct

Is it posible to define a structure with a pointer to that type of structure? What I mean is:

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    node* parent;
} node;
```

As far as I tried or read, I don't know how to do this or if it's even possible.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506366/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, but you have to name the structure, so that you can refer to it.

```
typedef struct node_ {
    char* name;
    struct node_ * parent;
} node;
```

The name `node` only becomes declared after the structure is fully defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's the *detail* I didn't know! :)

Answer (score 23):

You can use an `incomplete type` in the `typedef`:

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node {
  char *name;
  node *parent;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

This is how linked lists are made!

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you try it? You have to put a name to the structure, and yes, this is the way in that recursive data structures works.

Comment: OP said he already did try it.

Comment: But, as I wrote, I tried id - didn't work, so I asked here :)