# Typedefs, tagged and untagged structures, and incompatible pointer types

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Consider the following C code snippet:

```
typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}node;

void inorderTraversal(node *p){
    inorderTraversal(p->left);
    printf("%d",p->val);
    inorderTraversal(p->right);
}
```

If I write only `typedef struct` instead of `typedef struct node`, I get a warning saying "passing argument of incompatible pointer type" when I call `inorderTraversal(root)` in `main()`. Why do I get this warning even though the program doesn't show any error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't give a tag name to the struct,

```
struct node* left;
```

in the struct definition declares a new (incomplete) type `struct node`. So when you pass a pointer to that (incomplete) type, where a `node*` is expected, you're passing a pointer of an incompatible type.

When the struct you define has members that are pointers to the same type, you must be able to name that type in the definition, so the type must be in scope.

If you give the `struct` a name, the type is - from that point on - in scope and can be referred to, although not yet complete, as `struct node` (if the tag is `node`). After the typedef is complete, the type can then be referred to as either `struct node` or `node`, whichever you prefer.

But if you don't give the `struct` a tag, the type is anonymous until the typedef is complete, and cannot in any way be referred to before that. And since when the line

```
struct node *left;
```

is encountered, no type that `struct node` refers to is known, that line declares a new type, `struct node`, of which nothing is known. The compiler has no reason to connect that type with the one currently being defined. So at that point, the `struct` contains a member that is a pointer to an unknown incomplete type. Now, in `inorderTraversal`, when you call

```
inorderTraversal(p->left);
```

with `node *p`, by the definition of `node`, `p->left` is a pointer to the unknown incomplete type `struct node`. If `p` has been created so that `p->left` is actually a pointer to `node`, things will work nevertheless (except possibly on platforms where pointers to different types have different representations), but you're passing a pointer to one type where a pointer to a different type is expected. Since the one type is incomplete, it is incompatible with the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

```
"passing argument of incompatible pointer type"
```

Because node is unknown at that time. So it is considered as a new type.

```
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

void inorderTraversal(struct node *p){
    inorderTraversal(p->left);
    printf("%d",p->val);
    inorderTraversal(p->right);
}
```

Now node is declared as struct before using it. i.e  `struct node* left;` so there is no error.

Please refer to this also: [self referential struct definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition) 
 [C structure with pointer to self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813991/c-structure-with-pointer-to-self?lq=1)

Answer (score -4):

You cannot create an anonymous `typedef`, it has to have a name.  C does not support anonymous `struct` types.

A GCC extension will enable that feature though: `-fms-extensions`

Comment: You can typedef a struct without tag, you just can't refer to it in its own definition.

Comment: This used to be the case in C89 with many compilers, but C99 allows this. In fact, in C99, it's possible to return anonymous structs/enums/unions defined in the function declaration and also to define global variables and constants (including arrays) with anonymous structs/enums/unions.