# Linked lists when to use -> and when .?

Tags: c, linked-list

Let's say for a structure called Point with x, y and next; when do I write `P.y` and when `P -> next` because for this code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
    struct Point *next;
} Point;
```

I cannot use `P -> next` nor can I try `if (P == NULL)`.

1. Can I have combination of `P.x` and `P -> next`?
2. When must I use -> and when . ?

Comment: This question might be a duplicate.

Comment: Everything is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `P` has type `Point`, then you always use `.`.

```
 Point p;
 p.next;
```

If `P` has type `Point*`, then you always use `->`.

```
 Point* p
 p->next;
```

If you really want to use `.` in the latter case, you have to deference first.

```
Point *p;
(*p).next;
```

Only in the latter case, it makes sense to check `p == NULL`, because a pointer can be `NULL` but a structure generally is not.

---

Since `next` is itself declared as a pointer, then you should use `->` for following the pointer to **its** next pointer.

```
Point p;
p.next->next; // Will only work if p.next is NOT NULL.

Point* p;
p->next->next; // Will only work if p->next is NOT NULL.
```

---

**Update**: To remove the warning, change your declaration to the following.

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x, y;
    struct Point *next;
} Point;
```

The problem is that the outside declaration is using the `typedef` and not the `struct`'s tag, while the inside is using `struct Point`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708897/typedefs-struct-tag-and-alias) for details about why you get this behavior.

Comment: but for *next I cant use -> next, it says invalid type

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu, That is because `p->` is shorthand for `(*p).`

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu, See the updates to my answer.

Comment: why am I getting a warning for somePoint -> next = otherPoint when they are bouth Point * and next is struct Point *next ?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu, What does the warning say?

Comment: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  current-> next = newPoint;

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu, Please show the declaration of `newPoint`.

Comment: Point *newPoint = (Point *) malloc ( sizeof(Point) );
    newPoint -> next = NULL;

Answer (score 3):

You use `P->next` when `P` is a pointer type `Point*`, and you use `P.next` when it's the actual struct of type `Point`.