# Referencing struct within a struct generates "incompatible-pointer-types" warnings

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Compiling and executing the following snippet:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    int count;
    struct lval **cell;
} lval;

lval *lval_new(void) {
    lval *v = malloc(sizeof(lval));
    v->cell = NULL;
    return v;
}

lval *lval_add(lval *x, lval *y) {
    x->count++;
    x->cell = realloc(x->cell, sizeof(lval *) * x->count);
    x->cell[x->count - 1] = y;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    lval *x = NULL;
    x = lval_new();
    x = lval_add(x, lval_new());
}
```

will generates the following warning under gcc:

```
foo.c:16:31: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct lval *' from 'lval *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        x->cell[x->count - 1] = y;
```

Modifying the code of `lval_add` and adding a `(struct lval*)` cast on `y` as below:

```
lval *lval_add(lval *x, lval *y) {
    x->count++;
    x->cell = realloc(x->cell, sizeof(lval *) * x->count);
    x->cell[x->count - 1] = (struct lval *) y;
    return x;
}
```

fixes this warning.

It feels unnatural to me (disclaimer: I'm not a skilled C programmer) and I must add several cast to fix these warnings in my program.
Is there  a better way to declare the `lval` structure so that it would not generate these warnings?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? I think there's problem in your structure declaration or you'me ommitting code.

Comment: `struct lval` is a different type to `lval`

Comment: @M.M and we don't see any `struct lval` here, right sir? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh We see 1 or 2

Comment: `lval` and `struct lval` are different unrelated types unless explicitly linked to each other with a `typedef` name declaration (which sjould feature the identifier `lval` **twice**: `typedef struct lval ... lval;`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typedefs, struct tag, and alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708897/typedefs-struct-tag-and-alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your structure definition, the symbol `lval` doesn't exist yet. It doesn't exist until the structure has already been defined. And then not as a structure but as a type-name.

There are two ways of solving the problem, both needing you to name the structure.

The first one is very close to what you're already doing:

```
typedef struct lval {  // <- Note giving the structure a name
    int count;
    struct lval **cell;  // <- Using the structure name
} lval;
```

The second is to define the type-alias before you define the structure:

```
typedef struct lval lval;  // Create type-name

struct lval {
    int count;
    lval **cell;  // <- Use the type-name
};
```

---

Also note that you do not initialize the `count` member of the structure. That means its value will be *indeterminate* and using it might lead to *undefined behavior*.

In your `lval_new` function you need to set it to zero explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code is just an extract of what I am doing (for readiness). So yes, it is rather incomplete, count is properly initialized in the complete code.

Comment: @ohe If you don't want us to answer the wrong questions, make the wrong guesses, or note details that are wrong, then it's important that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: well. My question concerned a warning raised by the compiler on a structure. The given code is then minimal, complete and verifiable in this context. You're not answering a wrong question. You're answering a question that isn't asked. For the question I asked, your answer is, by far, the best. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your struct isn't called `struct lval`.

try

```
typedef struct lv {
  int count;
  struct lv **cell;
} lval;
```

because the struct should be either `struct lv` or `lval`.

Answer (score 2):

In this declaration

```
typedef struct {
    int count;
    struct lval **cell;
} lval;
```

there are declared two different entities. The first one is a double pointer to incomplete type `struct lval` and the second one is an unnamed structure that gets alias name `lval`.

That is this part of the declaration

```
typedef struct {
```

starts a definition of an unnamed struct while this part of the declaration

```
    struct lval **cell;
```

introduces one more declaration of incomplete type `struct lval`.

So `struct lval` and `lval` denote different entities.

As result in this assignment statement

```
x->cell[x->count - 1] = y;
```

the left operand has type `struct lval *` while the right operand has type `lval *` where `lval` is an alias for an unnamed structure.

I think you mean

```
typedef struct lval {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    int count;
    struct lval **cell;
} lval;
```

In this case the name `lval` is an alias for the type `struct lval`.