# C struct, pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C : pointer to struct in the struct definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506366/c-pointer-to-struct-in-the-struct-definition)

In my beginer course we need to declare a struct for tree search. I need pointers for reference of same type in each node. This decleration seems incorrect, pnode is not known in this context. How can i archieve my goal?

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    int value;
    int right;
    int left;
    pnode nextleft;
    pnode nextright;
}node, *pnode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    int right;
    int left;
    struct node *nextleft;
    struct node *nextright;
};
```

Here, `node` is within the *tag* namespace.

Comment: +1 And if you want to avoid having to use `struct node` and `struct node *` to declare instances of your structure, you can still add `typedef struct node node;
typedef struct node* pnode;` after the structure definition.  Although for code clarity, I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 2):

the C Faq  is a good reference.  http://c-faq.com/struct/selfref.html

I tend to use the typedef before the struct method

http://c-faq.com/decl/selfrefstruct.html

```
   typedef struct a *APTR;
    typedef struct b *BPTR;

    struct a {
        int afield;
        BPTR bpointer;
    };

    struct b {
        int bfield;
        APTR apointer;
    };
```