# Can a struct have a member which is a pointer to a struct of the same type?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, qualifiers

Sounds super convoluted, but it's a simple concept.
Say you have some struct "foo" one if it's members is a pointer to another foo struct (like a linked list)

Which seems to work.

```
struct foo {
   struct foo* ptr;
};
```

But what if I wanted foo to be a type?

Like how would I do the following?

```
typedef struct foo {
   foo* ptr;
} foo;
```

The declaration of ptr fails since foo is not a qualifier yet.

Comment: Are you asking for c or c++? Pick one please!

Comment: To amplify the previous comment: C and C++ differ in this respect, so the two get different answers.

Comment: Looks like C, amended the tag, feel free to revert if you meant otherwise.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you doing `typedef struct foo { struct foo *ptr; } foo;` - you can have both a `struct _` and a `typedef` name for the same struct.

Comment: Are you a new `C` programmer?  Adding semicolons should be a reflex.

Comment: If you are asking about C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506366/c-pointer-to-struct-in-the-struct-definition

Comment: `Like how would I do the following?` In the definition just write `struct foo* ptr;` instead of `foo* ptr;`.

Comment: This is an *extremely* common thing to do, needed to define linked lists and binary trees, for example. Any decent C textbook or tutorial should cover it.

Comment: Thanks guys :)
Yea, C was preferable, but I added a C++ tag because if this was easier in C++ I wouldn't mind, since I'm sorta learning both C and C++ right now.

And yes, I am new to C, and programming in general.

Comment: You mean like a linked list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forward declare the definition.

```
typedef struct foo {
    struct foo* ptr
} foo;
```

Or you could forward declare the type declaration.

```
typedef struct node_t node_t;

typedef struct node_t {
   node_t *next;
} node_t;
```

Comment: For further reading see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Answer (score 1):

To go further in implementing Casper Von B's answer:

If you have a few variable types like int and maybe a char array in the struct, you will need to use malloc:

```
node_t *ptr = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

You can use the -> operator and . operator to choose the variable:

```
ptr -> x = 12;
```

Then, when finished use free() for garbage collection:

```
free(ptr);
```

My final note is you can continue to link structs together with pointers and then traverse through them.