# What is meant by struct node *next; in a linked list program made in c language?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

```
// Linked list implementation in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Creating a node
struct node {
  int value;


 struct node *next; //What is this, what are we doing here?
};

// print the linked list value
void printLinkedlist(struct node *p) {
  while (p != NULL) {
    printf("%d ", p->value);
    p = p->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  // Initialize nodes
  struct node *head;
  struct node *one = NULL;
  struct node *two = NULL;
  struct node *three = NULL;

  // Allocate memory
  one = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  two = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  three = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  // Assign value values
  one->value = 1;
  two->value = 2;
  three->value = 3;

  // Connect nodes
  one->next = two;
  two->next = three;
  three->next = NULL;

  // printing node-value
  head = one;
  printLinkedlist(head);
}
```

I want to ask what are we doing here with this line of code?
**it's in the creating a node part of the code (top)**.

```
struct node *next;
```

Are we assigning a pointer type struct variable for the `sturct node` but its inside of the same struct, assigning a variable named `*next` inside the same struct? But that isn't allowed, right?

we can either declare the variable out side the `}` and between `;` or in the `main()`
function part of the code only, Isn't it?

Like

```
main()
{
struct node *next;
}
```

Again, then I came across a post mentioning it as a pointer to the structure itself, can anyone explaine how can we do this inside the same struct?

[image: Post img]

Comment: It's a member of the struct that is a pointer to an instance of the struct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C: pointer to struct in the struct definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506366/c-pointer-to-struct-in-the-struct-definition)

Comment: "*But that isn't allowed, right?*". No, not right. It is allowed.

Comment: We don't need a huge screenshot of a stackoverflow post, thank you very much. A link is quite enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next` member points to another instance of `struct node`.  Graphically, we usually represent it like this:

```
+–––––––+––––––+      +–––––––+––––––+  
| value | next |––––> | value | next |
+–––––––+––––––+      +–––––––+––––––+
```

A `struct` type cannot contain an instance of itself - we can’t create a type like

```
struct node {
  int value;
  struct node next;
};
```

for two reasons:

- The type definition isn’t complete until the closing `}`, and you cannot create an instance of an incomplete type;
- The type would require infinite storage (`struct node` contains a member `next` of type `struct node` which contains a member `next` of type `struct node` which contains a member `next` of type `struct node`...);

However, we can declare `next` as a *pointer* to `struct node`, since we can create pointers to incomplete types.  The size and representation of a pointer is independent of the size and representation of the type it points to.

Comment: Best to the point answer, you really cleared two of my concepts with one answer. Thankyou. ❤

Answer (score 2):

### What it means

The line `struct node *next;` is read as "next is a pointer to another struct node".

This is just a recursive structure declaration (definition):

```
struct node {
  int value;
 struct node *next; //What is this, what are we doing here?
};
```

It says a node consist of two parts:

1. an integer value
2. a pointer to another node.

The wiki article on [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) has a nice visualization showing how one node points to another (or to NULL to end the chain).

### How does it work?

As you noted, the interesting part is how the declaration can include a reference back to itself.  The compiler handles this in two steps:

1. It sizes the struct as consisting of an int and a pointer (they're all the same size regardless of what they are pointing to).
2. Later it type checks the assignment and generates the appropriate assembly.  When you write `one->value = 1;`, it makes sure the 1 is an integer and generates code to move 1 to the integer slot.  And when your write `one->next = two;`, it verified that *two* is a pointer to a node and generates code to move that pointer to the second slot for the struct node pointer.